# ClassNotFoundException while implementing SupportKit in android

Tags: android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, supportkit, smooch

I am trying to implement chat service with users using [SupportKit](http://supportkit.io) library in my android app. I followed all steps mentioned [here](http://docs.supportkit.io/android/) in eclipse to implement this feature. I am using SupportKit 1.0.0 version in Eclipse. But everytime I try to run it I am getting ClassNotFoundException on io.supportkit.ui.ConversationActivity.

Log:

```
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122): Process: com.example.saplesupport, PID: 9122
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lio/supportkit/ui/ConversationActivity;
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at com.example.saplesupport.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:23)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4759)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19770)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.supportkit.ui.ConversationActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.saplesupport-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     ... 11 more
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.supportkit.ui.ConversationActivity
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         ... 13 more
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.supportkit.ui.ConversationActivity
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):         ... 12 more
09-02 15:15:21.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9122):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```